# How to capture a cell when entered or selected?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to capture, programmatically, the `on cell entered` and `on cell selected` method, but I don't seem to be able to find any documentation on it.

I can get the time stamp for exiting the cell through the `onEdit` trigger but I can't figure the other two out. Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately that is currently not possible. The available triggers are

- onEdit
- onOpen
- onInstall

plus Time-Driven triggers.

[Here's the documentation.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Maybe when the onEdit event is fired it records the time that the edit started to occur instead of when the user exits the cell.

Comment: Sure! No, I believe it fires when you have finished editing the cell.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm looking into the .net gdata library. Still figuring out its usefulness or appropriateness but the documentation mentions lots of cell entry function
https://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn/docs/